# Display Information in a dynamic created calender with VBA (Powerquery, BI?)

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have about 10.000 rows of time sheets of workers in excel. The data looks like this:

```
Description  |       Date       | Start Time | End time | Worker  | Duration
First contact    4.4.2063         16:00       18:00      HP           02:00
 Assimilation    8.6.2098         13:30       14:50      KF           01:20
```

and so on.

I want to display this information in calender form for an easier overview. Some projects are worked by different people and sometimes even at the same time. In an optimal world there will be visual indicators for each day, as well as the ability to pop the calender up to see the values for the day. While I found some interesting stuff while googling, none of the advice really gave a solution.

I am especially interested if microsoft or a third party actually introduced a solution for my problem, maybe in powerquery or the new products coming out.

In any case, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Sounds tough.. here might be a good place to start looking..

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Power-View-Explore-visualize-and-present-your-data-98268d31-97e2-42aa-a52b-a68cf460472e

Comment: you could create a calendar sheet of known size and position, then add some columns to your table with formulae to dtermine x and y cordinates on your calendar, then create a for loop in VBA to create a shape for each row. You might then consider adding a macro to each shape to bring through the desired information

Answer (score 0):

Power BI has a Custom Visual to make a Gantt Chart:

https://app.powerbi.com/visuals/show/Gantt1448688115699

Before you get too excited, the lowest granularity is Day.  It's all open source, so all you need is a friendly JavaScript developer to extend it ...